# One jack and one club

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

How many ways a player can be dealt exactly one jack and exactly one club ?
Of course, A player can be dealt 5 cards in a normal poker game

So we have 4 different jacks and 13 different club cards. However, one of the jack is already a club.

The way I think is that I just choose one of the 4 jack cards and then 1 of the 12 club cards (I excluded here the jack). And now we have $$52 - (4 + 12) = 36$$ different cards to choose 3 cards from.

so the answer should be $${4 \choose 1} \times {12 \choose 1} \times {36 \choose 3}$$

But then I may have chosen a jack of clubs, then we are not allowed to have another club. How can I account for this ?

Comment: You've ignored the case where the jack you chose is the jack of clubs - then you don't want to choose another club.

Comment: So for case 1 we have $ 36 \choose 4 $ and for case 2 we have 
${3 \choose 1} \times {12 \choose 1} \times {36 \choose 3}$  is that correct ? and then we add the 2 cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

- You get the jack of clubs, and 4 cards which are neither jacks nor clubs, or:
- You get a non-club jack, a non-jack club, and 3 cards which are neither jacks nor clubs.

These are disjoint possibilities. Count each of them up separately.

Comment: So for case 1 we have $ 36 \choose 4 $ and for case 2 we have 
${3 \choose 1} \times {12 \choose 1} \times {36 \choose 3}$  is that correct ? and then we add the 2 cases

Comment: @alkabary: Yes, both are correct.